# SDK Manager: Cant launch it using the "android program" in the tools folder of the SDK(MAC)

Tags: android

sorry to bother, but I'm new to java SDK and android SDK. Im trying to open up the SDK manager and after going into the tools folder and opening up the "android" program, I get this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Copyright 2005-2007, The Android Open Source Project
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Set up prog to be the path of this script, including following symlinks,
# and set up progdir to be the fully-qualified pathname of its directory.
prog="$0"

    while [ -h "${prog}" ]; do
        newProg=`/bin/ls -ld "${prog}"`
        newProg=`expr "${newProg}" : ".* -> \(.*\)$"`
        if expr "x${newProg}" : 'x/' >/dev/null; then
            prog="${newProg}"
        else
            progdir=`dirname "${prog}"`
            prog="${progdir}/${newProg}"
        fi
    done
    oldwd=`pwd`
    progdir=`dirname "${prog}"`
    cd "${progdir}"
    progdir=`pwd`
    prog="${progdir}"/`basename "${prog}"`
    cd "${oldwd}"

    jarfile=sdkmanager.jar
    frameworkdir="$progdir"
    if [ ! -r "$frameworkdir/$jarfile" ]
    then
        frameworkdir=`dirname "$progdir"`/tools/lib
    fi
    if [ ! -r "$frameworkdir/$jarfile" ]
    then
        frameworkdir=`dirname "$progdir"`/framework
    fi
    if [ ! -r "$frameworkdir/$jarfile" ]
    then
        echo `basename "$prog"`": can't find $jarfile"
        exit 1
    fi


    # Check args.
    if [ debug = "$1" ]; then
        # add this in for debugging
        java_debug=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8050,suspend=y
        shift 1
    else
        java_debug=
    fi

    java_cmd="java"

    # Mac OS X needs an additional arg, or you get an "illegal thread" complaint.
    if [ `uname` = "Darwin" ]; then
        os_opts="-XstartOnFirstThread"
    else
        os_opts=
    fi

    if [ `uname` = "Linux" ]; then
        export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true
    fi

    if [ "$OSTYPE" = "cygwin" ] ; then
        jarpath=`cygpath -w  "$frameworkdir/$jarfile"`
        jarpath="$jarpath;"`cygpath -w  "$frameworkdir/swtmenubar.jar"`
        progdir=`cygpath -w  "$progdir"`
    else
        jarpath="$frameworkdir/$jarfile:$frameworkdir/swtmenubar.jar"
    fi

    # Get the current content of java.ext.dirs so that we can add to it instead of replacing
    javaExtDirs=`"${java_cmd}" -jar "${frameworkdir}/archquery.jar" java.ext.dirs`

    # Figure out the path to the swt.jar for the current architecture.
    # if ANDROID_SWT is defined, then just use this.
    # else, if running in the Android source tree, then look for the correct swt folder in prebuilt
    # else, look for the correct swt folder in the SDK under tools/lib/
    swtpath=""
    if [ -n "$ANDROID_SWT" ]; then
        swtpath="$ANDROID_SWT"
    else
        vmarch=`"${java_cmd}" -jar "${frameworkdir}/archquery.jar"`
        if [ -n "$ANDROID_BUILD_TOP" ]; then
            osname=`uname -s | tr A-Z a-z`
            swtpath="${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/prebuilts/tools/${osname}-${vmarch}/swt"
        else
            swtpath="${frameworkdir}/${vmarch}"
        fi
    fi

    if [ ! -d "$swtpath" ]; then
        echo "SWT folder '${swtpath}' does not exist."
        echo "Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform."
        exit 1
    fi

        # need to use "java.ext.dirs" because "-jar" causes classpath to be ignored
        exec "$java_cmd" \
            -Xmx256M $os_opts $java_debug \
            -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="$progdir" \
            -classpath "$jarpath:$swtpath/swt.jar" \
            com.android.sdkmanager.Main "$@"
```

And no SDK manager platform. Ive watched other videos where the person just opens up the android program and the SDK manager starts. Any ideas? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a little hard to tell, but i guess you're double-clicking on the file and viewing its contents in a text editor?

so, your problem is the script is opening with the wrong program. instead of a text editor, it should open with your command shell. see [this article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1152586/openwith.html) if you aren't familiar with the process of changing the app used to open a file.

Comment: That was it. Sorry for my ignorance, but thanks for pointing that out, it cure my headache!